# What is the right way to quote nested parameter expansions?

Tags: shell, quoting, posix, variable-substitution

When dealing with with nested parameter expansions, which of these is the correct way to quote things?

This one:

```
var="${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
```

Or this one:

```
var="${var#${var%%[![:space:]]*}}"
```

I have seen it done both ways. The first variation is a snippet from [a Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3352015). It is one of the most highly upvoted answers to the question (the question being about how to trim whitespace from a variable).

---

I'm also having trouble finding a reputable source that addresses how to quote things when working with a "word" or "pattern" that is a variable instead of literal text. Of the two below, which is correct?

This one:

```
strip_ext="${filename%."$filename_ext"}"
```

Or this one:

```
strip_ext="${filename%.$filename_ext}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, the first way is usually what you want. When the string on the right side of `${var#*a}` is not quoted it is interpreted/expanded as a pattern. In this example removing the leading text up to the first letter `a`. If quoted: `${var#"*a"}` the expansion would remove a literal `*a`. That may be a problem if in:

```
"${filename%."$filename_ext"}"
```

the `"$filename_ext"` may contain pattern characters. Similarly, if `$var` in `"${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"` could contain pattern characters (*?[) and you do not want them interpreted as a pattern, then quote the expansion as:

```
"${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
```

Note that the right side of a variable assignement is considered quoted and doesn't need (but cause no harm) quotes, this two are also correct:

```
      var=${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}
strip_ext=${filename%."$filename_ext"}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to depend on how you want the right-hand side of the expansion interpreted. As a pattern, or as a literal string.

Here, the unquoted `*` is a pattern, and eats the whole string. The quoted one just removes a literal asterisk:

```
var='foo*'
echo ":${var%%*}:"                 # this prints ::
echo ":${var%%"*"}:"               # this prints :foo:
```

It's the same if the put the pattern through a variable:

```
var='foo*'
pat='*'
echo ":${var%%$pat}:"              # this prints ::
echo ":${var%%"$pat"}:"            # this prints :foo:
```

Or with another parameter expansion on the right side:

```
var='foo*'
pat='x*x'
echo ":${var%%${pat//x}}:"         # this prints ::
echo ":${var%%"${pat//x}"}:"       # this prints :foo:
```

(`${pat//x}` results in just `*` again.)

I get the same behaviour with all POSIX-like shells I tried (Bash, ksh, yash). Zsh is different of course, all parameter expansions on the right side act like they're quoted there, like they do in relation to word-splitting issues too. I suppose there's some operator that can be used in an expansion to change that.